# Bootstrap wysi html5 send me text in database with big line-height

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have the next code

```
 <div class="form-group">

                    <label>Program</label>

                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body pad">
                        <form>
                            <textarea id="text-area-first" name="text-area-first" required class="textarea" placeholder="Place some text here" style="width: 50%; height: 150px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I'm inserting text in texbox everything looks good, but when I go to see the result on page it gives me a big line-height and I don't know why.

The result in database is:

```
<p>Text:</p>
<p>My text</p>
<p>always text</p>
```

Comment: This is PURELY, CSS `<p>` has a margin-bottom in bootstrap

Comment: But how exactly can I edit the margin-bottom only for this <p> ? How can I add class for this <p> ?

Comment: Most WYSIWYG's have the ability to "Edit as HTML" though see my answer for what is hopefully a simpler solution to your headache.

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be `line-height` here stems from the use of multiple "paragraph" tags, your issue is in the definition itself, a paragraph separates itself from other paragraphs.

The way you would want to output this generally is

```
<p>
    Text:<br/>
    My Text<br/>
    Always text<br/>
<p>
```

It's good practice to avoid saving HTML in database as often as possible. Though as you're using a WYSIWYG editor, your solution can only be found in modifying the CSS.

Most WYSIWYG editors allow for Ctrl+Enter (Cmd+Enter) to move to a new line (which will create the `<br/>` while staying within the `<p>` parent, pressing enter alone will generally create a new paragraph tag; ergo, your issue.

But ultimately, it's `margin-bottom` on the `<p>` tag within bootstraps css

Comment: Not working to move on a new line with Ctrl+Enter or Cmd+Enter :(. How can I change the margin bottom specific for this paragraphs?

Comment: I can't answer that without seeing the **entire** output. Try Shift+Enter. Are you able to tell me what WYSIWYG editor you're using as I wasn't aware bootstrap shipped with one.

Comment: It's working with Shift-Enter but still put my text in <p> and that is create me the space. I'm using bootstrap WYSIHTML5.